# Byte array written to isolated storage area file in C# Windows Phone 7 app is invalid

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7.1, isolatedstorage, binarywriter

I have a C# Windows Phone 7.1 app that downloads a PDF file from a foreign web server and then (tries) to save it to the isolated storage area as a file.  I have tried several different ways to get this done, but the file always ends up about 30% too large and when I open it up in a text editor, instead of seeing the USUAL 'PDF' characters at the start of the file followed by the encoded characters, I see basically junk.  The test file I'm using is supposed to be 161k but when I view the file with the [Isolated Storage Explorer](http://wp7explorer.codeplex.com/), it's 271k.

First I download the file to a string.  I inspected the string at this point in the debugger and it does contain the proper values and it is the correct length.  The trouble happens when I try to write it to the isolated storage area.  I tried both **StreamWriter** & **BinaryWriter** with identical invalid results. The contents of the resulting file appears to be a long stream of junk characters. Note, I am deleting the file if it exists just in case, before writing out the contents.  Below is my code using the **BinaryWriter** version.  What is wrong?

```
async public static Task URLToFileAsync(
                                string strUrl, 
                                string strDestFilename, 
                                IProgress<int> progress, 
                                CancellationToken cancelToken)
{
    strUrl = strUrl.Trim();

    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strUrl))
        throw new ArgumentException("(Misc::URLToFileAsync) The URL is empty.");

    strDestFilename = strDestFilename.Trim();

    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strDestFilename))
        throw new ArgumentException("(Misc::URLToFileAsync) The destination file name is empty.");

    // Create the isolated storage file.
    // FileStream fs = Misc.CreateIsolatedStorageFileStream(strDestFilename);
    IsolatedStorageFile isoStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

    // Delete the file first.
    if (isoStorage.FileExists(strDestFilename))
        isoStorage.DeleteFile(strDestFilename);

    IsolatedStorageFileStream theIsoStream = isoStorage.OpenFile(strDestFilename, FileMode.Create);

    FileStream fs = theIsoStream;

    // If the stream writer is NULL, then the file could not be created.
    if (fs == null)
        throw new System.IO.IOException("(Misc::URLToFileAsync) Error creating or writing to the file named: " + strDestFilename);

    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);

    try
    {

        // Call URLToStringAsync() to get the web file as a string first.
        string strFileContents = await URLToStringAsync(strUrl, progress, cancelToken);

        // >>>> NOTE: strFileContents looks correct and is the correct size.

        // Operation cancelled?
        if (!safeCancellationCheck(cancelToken))
        {
            // Note.  BinaryWriter does not have an Async method so we take the hit here
            //  to do a synchronous operation.
            //  See this Stack Overflow post.
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315316/asynchronous-binaryreader-and-binarywriter-in-net

            // >>>> NOTE: strFileContents.ToCharArray() looks correct and is the correct length.
            bw.Write(strFileContents.ToCharArray(), 0, strFileContents.Length);
        } // if (safeCancellationCheck(cancelToken))
    }
    finally
    {
        // Make sure the file is cleaned up.
        bw.Flush();
        bw.Close();

        // Make sure the file is disposed.
        bw.Dispose();
    } // try/finally

    // >>>> NOTE: output file in Isolated Storage Explorer is the wrong size and contains apparently junk.
} // async public static void URLToFileAsync
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot download a binary into a string. The result will not be correct, as you have found out.

See this answer, which demonstrates how to download a binary file to isolated storage: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6909201/1822514

Comment: @chue_x.  Thanks.  That worked but I would like to know why, especially since the length of the string is identical to the size of the web file.  The only reason for the difference I can think of is that C#/.NET stores strings with multi-byte encoding or some other encoding in the string memory itself, something that at least non-.NET C, C++, and Delphi does not do.

Comment: @RobertOschler **All strings in .NET are encoded in UTF-16**. So when reading a string, the runtime will try to convert the characters into that encoding. When unable to find out which encoding the source has used, it will default to UTF-8. So basically, in your case, .NET thought your PDF file was an UTF-8 encoded text, and converted it to UTF-16. Since both encoding do not have the same binary representation, it explains why your data got corrupted.

Comment: @KooKiz - That explains it, thanks.  I've switched everything to byte arrays and all is well now.